# How would you calculate induced voltage from a radiated electric field?

Tags: voltage, induction

This may be somewhat of a classical question based upon Radiated susceptibility testing performed in avionics qualification testing; given a given electric field strength (V/m) at a given frequency, provided by radiated susceptibility test limits, how would you be able to calculate the amount of induced voltage on a floating wire 1-meter away?

For example, say you need to subject a harness during Radiated Susceptibility testing of 100 V/m from 2 MHz to 30 GHz.  The test setup occurs 1-meter away from the EUT harness.  Would it be possible to calculate the amount of induced voltage to a wire in the harness (assuming it is not shielded)?

Comment: What's the wires capacitance to earth?